# BIOS Int 13h 08 DBT issue Bytes per sector code returns 0xF0 instead of 0x00 - 0x04

Tags: assembly, interrupt, x86-16, bios, fasm

I was using int 13h 08 to load disk parameters and got an invalid value from the disk base table (dbt).
The value in question was 0xF0.
note: dbt is returned in es:di

Reference to int 13h 08: https://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_13-8.html
Reference to dbt: https://stanislavs.org/helppc/dbt.html
repo link: https://github.com/The3Null4Player613310/RealOS

Code in question:

```
disk_get_params:                ; get primary disk params
    push es
    push es
    mov dl, [addr_svs_pdv]
    mov ah, 0x08
    int 13h

    push ds                 ; get dbt
    push es
    pop ds
    mov si, di

    pop ax                  ; set es
    pop es
    push ax

    shr dx, 0x08            ; set total head count
    inc dx
    mov [addr_svs_thc], dx

    call disk_get_sector    ; set sectors per track
    inc ax
    mov [addr_svs_spt], ax

    call disk_get_cylindar  ; set tracks per head
    mov [addr_svs_tph], ax

    ;add si, 0x03

    xor ah, ah              ; set bytes per sector
    lodsb
    lodsb
    lodsb
    lodsb

    mov cx, ax
    mov bx, 0x80
    shl bx, cl
    mov [addr_svs_bps], bx

    pop ds
    pop es
    jmp disk_return
```

Comment: You're saying one of the bytes in the DBT is 0xF0?  Which one?

Comment: It appears to be the fourth byte.

Comment: Also before the interupt is called es is 0x0000 and di is unknown.

Comment: Hmm, that does seem odd.  I can see how offset 03 (is that the one you're talking about?) might be larger than 4 (maybe as high as 6), but 0xF0 seems way out.  Do the other values look right?  How are you checking the contents of the DBT?  Did you set a breakpoint after the int 13?  Does the carry flag look right at that point?

Comment: yes offset 03 is correct. I'm using qemu without a debugger and using a call to int 13h E to display a char to check its value.

Comment: I haven't checked the carry flag yet.

Comment: [ascii codes](https://www.ascii-codes.com/) for bios.

Comment: When you do `lodsb`, is DS pointing to the DBT?  Or to the data segment where you want to store the values?  If it's the data segment, then you may be reading from the wrong place.  If it's the DBT, you may be writing to the wrong place when you `mov [addr_svs_bps], bx`.

Comment: DS:SI is used for lodsb so I moved es to ds and move ds to si then set es to 0x0000. It was my belief that es was for storing information, so that could be where I went wrong.

Comment: [link](http://www.husseinsspace.com/teaching/udw/1996/asmnotes/chaptwo.htm) might help, but overall confused me thoroughly.

Comment: How about if you just leave DS at the value you were called with, and let the `int 13` set ES.  Then you can read the value from the DBT with something like `mov bx,es:[3]`, and store it with `mov [addr_svs_bps], bx`.

Comment: I tried `mov cl, [es:di+bx]` where bx is 0x0003 I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: It is still 0xF0. So it seems that the memory location I was reading was right. My only thought is that I might have to move es:di to a known free location where it will populate a table, but that is only speculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet in the question is wrong in the way it uses the segment registers. It's not possible to draw any conclusions about the F0-issue from it. However the same code on your GitHub repository seems OK.

The BIOS.ReturnDiskDriveParameters function 08h will only return in `ES:DI` a far pointer to the DisketteParameterTable if the drive number that you specified in `DL` on entry referred to a floppy drive (`DL < 128`).
I have looked at your project on GitHub and believe that what happens here, is that this BIOS function did neither touch `ES` nor `DI`, and because both happen to contain 0 on entry (*), the code that follows will be using a NULL-pointer. An instruction like `mov cl, [es:di+3]` (or similar) will therefore read the 4th byte of linear memory which so happens to hold F0. The first vector of the InterruptVectorTable is the DivideException and points to somewhere in the BIOS code. A typical value being F000:EF6F (6F, EF, 00, **F0**).

(*) In your *boot.asm* on GitHub, you setup the `DS` and `ES` segment registers via `push cs` `push cs` `pop es` `pop ds`. This is dangerous! There's absolutely no guarantee that the `CS` segment register will hold the 0 that you need in accordance with your `ORG 7C00h` directive. It would be perfectly allright for the BIOS to reach your bootloader with `CS:IP = 07C0h:0000h`. The only valid way to setup is:

```
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
```

### What to do next?

- Always check the status that was reported by the system functions. The BIOS.ReturnDiskDriveParameters function 08h sets the carry flag if something was wrong. Don't omit a check for this situation!
- There exists a newer BIOS function that will report the drive parameters for hard drives exclusively.
  Read about the BIOS.GetDriveParameters function 48h in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H).
- It would be a very safe assumption to just consider BytesPerSector = 512. Many people have never seen anything else and for an hobby OS it might be the simplification you need...